# How to define world interest rate using IS-LM-BP diagram?

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate, exchange-rates, open-economy-macro, balance-of-trade

Can you suggest where is the world interest rate in the economy which has a positive current account and a financial account surplus, fixed exchange rate and relative capital immobility? The graph of this should look like this: [image: pic]
Since NX and FA are positive, BP line is righter than the intersection of IS and LM curves, so $i_0$ is the country's interest rate, but what is the world's one?

Comment: What is the BP line?

Comment: BP = BOP (Balance of payment) = NX + FA